# How to alter and debug views queries?

Tags: views, hooks, debugging

I'm trying to find the hook/module which can modify a views query.

The view is from Workbench module which is displaying the draft's of the actual user.

If I *Disable SQL rewriting* in the *Query settings* the display is ok,
so something is interfering.

What would be the method to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can alter a views query using [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7). Try to search in your codebase for this string **views_query_alter**, you should get a function in one of the custom module which is implementing hook_views_query_alter.

If it doesn't help, try to enable **query log using devel module**, so you will know what query are being executed for that page. Views also gives the **sql query that a particular display** will run. See if these two sql queries don't match. You can **see the diff** and then try to figure out which module might be adding the additional conditions to that query.

Comment: See also [`module_implements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_implements/7) to figure out who is implementing a particular hook.  Just remember to pass it the hook name without the "hook_" at the beginning.

Comment: Found this commands by the way [Drush](http://drush.ws) that I already use: #List implementations of a given hook and explore source of specified one.
`drush fnh anyhook` and #Show the source of specified function or method.
`drush fnv`